# iOS 8 adaptive layout cell

Tags: layout, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to customize a button inside a `UITableViewCell` inside a `UITableViewController` which is inside a `UISplitViewController`.
I thought that changing the width constraint of the button for Regular Width will hide the button on the iPad. Is not hiding it because if I log the trait collection of the `UITableViewController` class it gives me the following:

`<UITraitCollection: 0x7fe66146c1d0; _UITraitNameUserInterfaceIdiom = Pad, _UITraitNameDisplayScale = 2.000000, _UITraitNameHorizontalSizeClass = Compact, _UITraitNameVerticalSizeClass = Regular, _UITraitNameTouchLevel = 0, _UITraitNameInteractionModel = 1>`

This happens because I want the UISVC to show both master and detail view controllers. 
Is there a way to hide the button of the cell from storyboard without checking in code using an if statement (if traitnameuserinterfaceidiom == Pad)?